# Excel 2010 how do I modify x-axis values sort order

Tags: excel, charts, plot, excel-2010

I have created a dynamic chart to show frequency of an event depending on the time of day.
I have data classed by date and time:

```
DATE    TIME    UNIX TIME   RUNNING JOBS
28/11/2013  11:30   1385634600  1
28/11/2013  12:00   1385636400  1
28/11/2013  12:30   1385638200  1
...
12/12/2013  11:00   1386842400  1
12/12/2013  11:30   1386844200  1
12/12/2013  12:00   1386846000  0
```

I have created a dynamic chart and used Running Jobs mean as x-axis value and time as y-axis value:
[image]

I would like to centre my plot on 00:00 in order to make it more readable:
[image]

I didn't find a way to do it with the dynamic table/chart.
Is there another way to do it (except to copy the dynamic table values and sort them by hand)?

Thanks you.

Comment: You have to explain a little more what you want to do. You want it so that only 12 hours are showing?

Comment: On the first graph the X-axis values are sort by ascending order (from 00:00 to 23:30). I'd like to sort them on a custom order (from 12:30 to 00:00 to 11:30) like on the second graph.